# Exclude error codes from TRAP in Powershell

Tags: powershell, error-handling, powershell-trap

I'm running a script that fetches the Invoke-WebRequest status codes of some sites that I'm monitoring (like 504, 400, 200 and so forth).

I'm using the TRAP method to protocol errors into a text file that can be reviewed for later analysis.

The code is as follows:

```
Trap
{
write-host ("An error has occurred: "+$_.exception.message)
Write-Host ("Please see error message or log file")
$_.Exception.Message+" "+(Get-Date) | Out-File -Append "$PSScriptRoot\log.txt"
$_.Exception.InnerException.Message | Out-File -Append "$PSScriptRoot\log.txt"
$site                               | Out-File -Append "$PSScriptRoot\log.txt"
"---------------------------------" | Out-File -Append "$PSScriptRoot\log.txt"
}
```

Question:
Can I exclude trapping certain error codes like "503" ?

Comment: Windows PowerShell or PowerShell Core?

Comment: It is PowerShell
I'm currently testing if adding "Where({$_.Statuscode -ne "503"})" within the TRAP works

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it looks like trap statements can't be filtered or restricted because the TRAP always applies to the whole SCOPE.

But what you can do is to split up the error_type onto several TRAPS like:

```
"trap [[error_type]] {statement_list}"
```